# Mobile Browser Compatibility: Site dont pinch in iOS browser

Tags: html, ios, mobile

There is a strange activity with our sites, http://beta.bridalbook.ph when view in mobile.

When view in iOS the site don't pinch, but when view in android it pinch.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding user-scalable=yes to your viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

to give you

```
<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1", , user-scalable=no />
```

And I would move your Meta tage up near the top with the rest.

Comment: I am now using this code `<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />` but the page doesn't fit in apple mobile browser